# Installing cpanel on AWS EC2 with Node

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cpanel

I'm starting to use EC2 on Amazon and I'm planning to use Node.js as my server and for back end development. But I am really used to managing files via GUI and not CLI. That is why I want to install Cpanel on EC2. But I think cpanel comes with a web server like apache or nginx. So is it alright to install cpanel on EC2 if im planning to use node? Will there be any compatibility errors?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend selecting Instance type and storage accordingly if you are planning to use WHM/Cpannel.

You can install it on any server you want refer [this guide](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-cpanel-whm-centos-7/). I think WHM Takes care of webserver like apache that is installed with this package.

Although things you need to keep in mind are :

- you need pay for licence
- Load Balancing etc would be very difficult.
- Do not Forget to Assign a Static IP (Elastic IP)

Thanks

Comment: Can I run both apache and node together?

Comment: I just thought that there would be complication running two servers together

Comment: No it would not